# How to fix Flutter google map picker problem?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, sdk

I'm using google map picker. But appearing problem when I select place

```
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)



 return Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            LocationResult result = await showLocationPicker(
              context,
              "blablablagooglekey",
              initialCenter: LatLng(41.2995, 69.2401),
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              layersButtonEnabled: true,
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
            );
            print("result = $result");
            setState(() => _pickedLocation = result);
          },
          child: Text('Pick location'),
        ),
        Text(_pickedLocation.toString() ?? 'Test'),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

How can I fix this?

I need select place for meeting buttun.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to achieve map picker, try this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/map_picker.

```
          MapPicker(
            // pass icon widget
            iconWidget: SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/location_icon.svg",
              height: 60,
            ),
            //add map picker controller
            mapPickerController: mapPickerController,
            child: GoogleMap(
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              // hide location button
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              //  camera position
              initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
              onCameraMoveStarted: () {
                // notify map is moving
                mapPickerController.mapMoving!();
                textController.text = "checking ...";
              },
              onCameraMove: (cameraPosition) {
                this.cameraPosition = cameraPosition;
              },
              onCameraIdle: () async {
                // notify map stopped moving
                mapPickerController.mapFinishedMoving!();
                //get address name from camera position
                List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
                  cameraPosition.target.latitude,
                  cameraPosition.target.longitude,
                );

                // update the ui with the address
                textController.text =
                '${placemarks.first.name}, ${placemarks.first.administrativeArea}, ${placemarks.first.country}';
              },
            ),
          ),
```